# Books on concrete category theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

> Are there any books dealing with concrete categories *besides* "Joy of Cats"?

I find "Joy of Cats" hard to read and it is not always obvious that the concepts introduced are all that important or how they are important.

Please keep in mind that I'm specifically asking about *concrete* categories (those equipped with a faithful functor into another category, especially into $\mathsf{Set}$), not just categories.

As an example consider the questions: "How does a left-adjoint to the faithful functor into $\mathsf{Set}$ yield the concept of a subobject generated by a subset?" and "What property in my 'base' category is enough to ensure the  existence of enough projectives in my concrete category?".
These are (I'd say conceptually) questions about concrete categories, not mere categories.

Comment: How about  *Algebra* by Mac Lane and Birkhoff? Or *Categories for the Working Mathematician* by Mac Lane?

Comment: I wish to add that examples in *Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats* are always without proofs, so good knowledge of those examples is required. Hence it is not possible to learn “concrete” branches of mathematics (abstract algebra, abstract analysis) employing category theory from the beginning.

Comment: @beroal Yeah, I think we are in desperate need of an actual *introduction* to concrete categories, not just a reference.

Comment: @StefanPerko I guess that we need to figure it out ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

This book cannot exist.

A result due to Freyd states that *any category with finite limits is concrete if and only if, for every object, its class of regular subobjects is, in fact, a set.* This is a very mild condition to meet and thus the general theory of concrete categories is very close to being the theory of all abstract categories.

Comment: "Can be equipped with a functor to become a concrete category" is not the same as "is a concrete category"; or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can see Kucera's paper here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/00224049/1/4 on the topic that every category is a factorisation of a complex one. Hope it helps.